# Override web/template file

Tags: overriding, magento2

Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to override a file that is in web/template, it's the minicart/content.html file I would like to change, i've been searching but can't find out how!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the URL they are going to help you to override the template file ;

[Magento 2: How to override mini-cart default template html file?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/96540/magento-2-how-to-override-mini-cart-default-template-html-file)

Also one more link you can follow :

[how to override template files for magento2 extension](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/108788/how-to-override-template-files-for-magento2-extension/121702#121702)